# Chaining Active Record methods error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code that I use in my search forms.  I want to be able to chain the scoped method with the by_title, but I fail to see how.  I want to have the by_title as a method instead of just doing:

```
# Arel helpers
  class << self
    def by_city(city)
      where(['city_id = ?', city])
    end
    def by_title(title)
      where('title LIKE ?', "%#{title}%")
    end
  end


  def self.search(search_params)
    experiences = scoped
    experiences.self.by_title(search_params[:title]) if search_params[:title]
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you play with scopes this way:

```
scope :by_title, lambda { |title| where('title LIKE ?', "%#{title}%") }
scope :by_city,  lambda { |city|  where('city_id = ?', city) }
```

Comment: Scopes and class methods are the same. My problem is different.

Comment: Sorry, it's true; i think @Robin's answer is the good one. But, in any case, named_scopes looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

By just removing `self` it should work I think:

```
experiences = scoped
experiences.by_title(search_params[:title]) if search_params[:title]
```

The `scoped` method returns an anonymous scope which can be chained with other scopes/class-methods.